# popup window with confirmation box in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, popup

Hi I am trying to display a `confirmation box`. I wrote the code below, and when I click the `OK` or `Cancel` buttons, it should close the `popup window`. But it's not closing for me. Can anyone help me solve this? Below is the `html code`. One more thing. If I use `javascript` it shows error `$` is undefined. Can anyone help me solve this or suggest other options?

```
 <div class="box">
<a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
<div class="popup">
    <h2>Here i am</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
    <div class="content">
        Thanks for pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
    </div>
<asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="OK" />

        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
</div>
```

Comment: can you please provide the `java script` code?

Comment: I deleted that because it shows  error can you please tell me how to do in any other way

Comment: If the $ is undefined, it should like you are missing includes such as jquery

Comment: Oh is it what is that jquery?? can you please tell me what is that

Comment: What are you trying to confirm?  Is this a conformation for a parent page? if so, you might want to use regular html controls instead of asp controls.

Comment: like confirm box if click cancel the popup box should close if click ok the data in the popup box should load

Comment: yes to a parent page

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this**

```
function close_window() {
      if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
        close();
      }
    }
```

with HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:close_window();">x</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;">x</a>
```

Comment: where to use this href

Comment: `<a class="close" href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;">×</a>`

Comment: where to use this next to <a class